# Theory of Operation for Arc Lamp

Tags: power-supply, current-limiting, lamp

I am attempting to power an arc lamp (which I have) using a programmable power supply (which I have yet to source.) Though the lamp is rated at 1000w (37v at 27A) I would like to power it at about 800w in order to modify its emission spectra and extend its lifetime.

The lamp in question is out of production but nearly identical to an [Osram HBO 1000 W/D](https://www.osram.com/appsj/pdc/pdf.do?cid=GPS01_1028562&vid=PP_EUROPE_Europe_eCat&lid=EN&mpid=ZMP_56338). While the lamp housing is a modified [Christie Xenolite 1000 W lamphouse](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Vintage-Christie-Xenonlite-1000-W-Xenon-Lamphouse-with-Rectifier-used-condition/311787745145) fixture. The xenolite housing has been modified mechanically. The system had originally used a more modern (but still solid state) Christie power supply rather than the original [rectifier power supply](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Christie-1KW-Rectifier-Xenon-Arc-Lamp-Power-Supply-Nice-Shape-1K/282730884364). We smoked quite a few caps in that power supply when we tried to fire it up. AFAIK the igniter in the Xenolite lamphouse still works but we haven't actually seen a bulb light since only the igniter works.

When attempting to source a power supply I see items like a [Sorenson DCS 40-30E](http://www.programmablepower.com/dc-power-supply/DCS/Specifications.htm) which can supply 0-40V and 0-30A. This seems perfect for me. Reading through the manual, it describes operating the supply in current limiting mode and voltage limiting mode. I may have misunderstood the terms but it seems to me the operation of an arc lamp requires both current and voltage be limited as the lamp will draw any "available wattage."

So, to restate the question, what is the theory of operation for a arc lamp regarding voltage/ current regulation and how does one specify this in the design of a power supply?

Comment: Let me offer two apologies off the bat: first, sorry if this is a noob question. EE is not my strong suit. Second, sorry this is sort of a two part question. How to operate the lamp and how to choose the power supply seemed too intertwined to ask separately.

Comment: Citation from the manual about limiting current? Sounds suspicious.

Comment: Typically you need a high voltage for ignition and a ballast to provide relatively loss-free impedance to counter the negative resistance characteristic of the arc. This might be a bit too challenging for a self-described noob, I think.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany the enclosure for the lamp includes an igniter which is powered independently. My understanding is that relays operated by the lamp selector circuit (a tungsten lamp is also an option) control when power _to_ the ignitor and _from_ the lamp power supply are applied to it. I should also note that the integration of the power supply will be done by a qualified EE and tech. I've just been asked to source a power supply and don't want to look like an imbecile.

Comment: @EugeneSh. the operation of the power supply in current limiting mode is found on page 36 of the [manual.](http://www.programmablepower.com/dc-power-supply/DCS/downloads/DCS-E_1-2kW-Series_Operation_Manual_M362500-01_rK.pdf)

Comment: @PhotoScientist I though you are talking about some lamp description

Comment: @EugeneSh. Perhaps your question illustrates my confusion, then. Do arc lamps limit current inherently? If the lamp is designed for 1000w will it not always pull 1000w? In other words, if I supply 30v to the lamp, how do I make it only draw 26A for 800watts? will it not draw 33A instead? Would it even be limited to 33A?

Comment: Basically an Arc lamp power supply is very like a DC welder, it has a high strike voltage to initiate the Arc and a current limited supply when struck (the lamp does not have a fixed resistance). Using a conventional power supply with a CC mode is likely to be challenging and I'd suggest you might be better with a small TIG welder as a power supply.

Comment: I think that your question would be well served by adding more details of the arc lamp. We can certainly talk about the theory of a simple arc lamp, i.e. two electrodes in a frame, but you've mentioned that it has an igniter and some amount of control circuit. Specifications of the lamp will help narrow down what is needed.

Comment: The arc resistance is a complex function of V,I, t and temperature with a negative instantaneous effective series resistance(-ESR from avalanche effect) much lower than the  average load positive resistance of V/I=+R. If this is the Philips plasma bulb, it will need good specs for power regulated bandwidth and a Faraday cage.

Comment: Mercury arc lamps are becoming obsolete and there are large numbers of used power supplies and lamp housing on the surplus / used market. It might be easier to adapt one of these rather than building from scratch.

Comment: Poor protection from Relaxation oscillations and power interruptions may benefit from glass explosion protection due massive stored energy in Sorensen’s . Is it a plasma bulb?  They make good mobile jammers I understand.

Comment: @KevinReid I've updated my question to include details.

Comment: Excellent project! Was the original lamp made for DC or AC? You can tell by the shape of the electrodes. Apart from that, it’s what Eugene said, you just need to start it with enough voltage and enough sustained time to strike it, then any sufficient CC/CV power supply will do the job.

Comment: Igniters often apply high voltage AC for starting. Mating the igniter with a separate low-voltage-high-current supply can be tricky. Your 800W DC supply may be at risk of destruction by the igniter's high voltage.